# Can I do performance testing with Espresso, or should I use something else?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-espresso

I'm new to the performance world, and am trying to figure out how to write some performance tests. A friend suggested Espresso to me, but i'm having trouble figuring out if it can actually do the things I need. Here's what i'm looking to do:

- Time how long it takes for app A to start
- Launch app A. Launch app B. Time how long it takes to launch app A.
- Run some ADB commands
- Read logcat files

Does Espresso help/prevent any of that from being possible, or is all that done with just Java and Espresso doesn't have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works. You may try do the timing setup using @Before, and Check the timing result @After .

```
TimingLogger timings;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        timings = new TimingLogger("Timing",
                "Testing");
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        timings.dumpToLog();
    }
```